# Как отфильтровать все пустые значения в колонках которые соответстуют списку?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных, nan

Есть список:

```
 lst = ['ATR1','ATR2']
```

DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ATR1': [111, None, 444], 'ATR2': [None, None, 555], 'ATR3': [777,888,None]})
```

Нужно отфильтровать пустые значения в колонках, которые соответсвуют списку (строки из всех колонок должны быть пустыми).

Должно получится:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'ATR1': [111, 444], 'ATR2': [None,  555], 'ATR3': [777, None]})
```

Знаю, что можно отфильтровать все пустые значения в колонке, но нужно с учетом пустых значений в другой:

```
df = df[df['ATR2'].notnull()]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = df[df[lst].notna().any(axis=1)]
```

результат:

```
In [77]: res
Out[77]:
    ATR1   ATR2   ATR3
0  111.0    NaN  777.0
2  444.0  555.0    NaN
```